# Java Regex Fails to Find a match

Tags: java, regex, string

This should return true, but instead returns false.

```
"ADC".matches("A.*?C")
```

I've tested it on a javascript regex tester : http://regexpal.com/

and it works, why doesn't it work in Java?

EDIT: 
Same with this:

```
System.out.println("DEAGHHF".matches("(A.*?C|C.*?A|D.*?C|C.*?D|A.*?F|F.*?A)"));
```

Returns false, regexpal returns true (aswhile as other javascript regex engines).

Comment: Sorry, for the little advert (i only use the tool myself, i don't work for them) but you can try the software regexpal mentions "regexbuddy" which allows you to even export a function to use in Java.

Comment: Are you sure that you have shown us the right expression and input? That expression matches that input on regexpal.com for me and when I run `"ADC".matches("A.*?C")`.

Comment: Why should DEAGHHF match A.?C|C.?A|D.?C|C.?D|A.?F|F.?A The regexp says that the string should be of length 2 or 3. The string that you have is way longer than that, so you can only get a partial match.

Comment: There were asteriks misssing, it should match with "A.*?F"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [it returns true](http://ideone.com/7eSOG).

```
System.out.println("ADC".matches("A.*?C"));
```

prints `true`.

The regexpal.com implementation seems to be buggy (which is understandable since it is version 0.1.4). Try entering `ABC` repeatedly. Only every second `ABC` gets rejected. (At least when viewing it in my version of firefox.)

**Regarding your edit:**

```
A.?C|C.?A|D.?C|C.?D|A.?F|F.?A
```

is interpreted as

```
A.*?C   or
C.*?A   or
D.*?C   or
C.*?D   or
A.*?F   or
F.*?A
```

In other words

```
Something that starts with A and ends with C, or
Something that starts with C and ends with A, or
Something that starts with D and ends with C, or
....
Something that starts with F and ends with A,
```

Since `"DEAGHHF`" starts with `D` and ends with `F`, it won't match.

Perhaps you're looking for the [`Matcher.find` method](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

Comment: Yeah works for me too. For testing RegEx for Java I recommend http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html - got that from SO myself. Really great implementation with quite some useful bells and whistles (especially the "get regex as java string" is awesome!)

Comment: Sorry the asteriks didn't show up, fixed first post again. Thanks

Comment: Matcher was what I was looking for, correct, thank you. And your explanation of the regex was helpful.